# onclick action doesnt perform properly in listview

Tags: android, android-listview

I used a listview in a android app. Each row of listview is consisted with  two textviews,one textview(named `text1`) to show a word from the database and another textview(named `text2`) for showing the meaning of that word from the database.Showing of listview worked fine. I wanted to show the word and the meaning from the listview whenever i clicked on a row(item)of a listview. But this actions doesn't work well, it's getting 'forced close' .
I used this code:

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            mDbHelper.open();

            String ss=s.toString();// get the word from the edittext 

             ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list_of_wordmeanings = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

            Cursor mCursor = mDbHelper.getTestData(ss);// get the rows from the database matched with EditText data

            for (int i = 0; i < mCursor.getCount(); i++) 
            {
                mCursor.moveToPosition(i);


                HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    String word = mCursor.getString(0).toString();
                    String meaning = mCursor.getString(1).toString();

                      hm.put("key_word",word);
                      hm.put("key_meaning",meaning);

                      list_of_wordmeanings.add(hm);
            }

                    String[] from = { "key_word","key_meaning" };
                    int[] to = { R.id.txt1,R.id.txt2};
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), list_of_wordmeanings, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);

                    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            } // end of afterTextChanged

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                          @Override
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                             int position, long id) {

                              Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


                               String english_word =
                                cursor.getString(0);
                               String word_meaning =
                                        cursor.getString(1);

                               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),english_word+word_meaning, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

My LogCat shows these:

```
08-05 10:34:13.470: W/KeyCharacterMap(15079): No keyboard for id 0
08-05 10:34:13.470: W/KeyCharacterMap(15079): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-05 10:34:15.150: W/dalvikvm(15079): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at com.example.chondrokotha5.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:136)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-05 10:34:15.159: E/AndroidRuntime(15079):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-05 10:35:13.449: W/KeyCharacterMap(15090): No keyboard for id 0
08-05 10:35:13.449: W/KeyCharacterMap(15090): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-05 10:35:16.250: W/dalvikvm(15090): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090): java.lang.ClassCastException:  java.util.HashMap
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at com.example.chondrokotha5.MainActivity$2.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:136)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 08-05 10:35:16.260: E/AndroidRuntime(15090):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What should i do to show the string of two rextview in from the listview ??
Please anyone tell me what i am doing wrong and whatz the solution????

Comment: can you post the stack trace?

Comment: i thinku have writtes listview onClickListener inside EditText afterTextChanged method.

Comment: I put it after the EditText afterTextChanged method and then also shows error and i posted it in my question.Check this please.@AndroidKiller

Comment: Check again my question please @kalyanpvs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your onclick.. it worked for me..

```
HashMap<String, String> sss = (HashMap<String, String>) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), sss.get("key_word")+"---"+sss.get("key_meaning"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Why your are receiving a class cast exception is, you have populated the listview with the data in **list_of_wordmeanings** hashmap in the line:

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), list_of_wordmeanings, R.layout.list_layout, from, to);
```

But you are trying to retrieve a cursor object in listview onItemClick.

Comment: From my LogCat message how can i understand this mistakes ?? @Tamilan

Comment: @Bayazid Just copy the error (`java.lang.ClassCastException:  java.util.HashMap`) and **google** about it.. You will get idea abt them.